# Using CLBeaconRegion with Apple Watch

Tags: core-location, core-bluetooth, watchos-4

I have been doing my research and can't find anything on this. Is it possible to use an Apple Watch as an iBeacon? CLBeaconRegion is not available :(

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. In order to support iBeacon you have to use the Core Bluetooth framework to configure the iOS device as a Bluetooth peripheral. watchOS and tvOS only support Bluetooth central.